# pdf miner adding extra new lines

Tags: python, pdf, langchain, pdfminer, pdf-parsing

While employing  PDFMinerLoader to parse PDF files, I've observed that it introduces additional new lines when encountering bullets or numbers. For example:

Original pdf:

1. use the...
2. replace the..
3. update the..

I got:

```
1.
2.
3.
use the..
replace the..
update the..
```

Similar issues occur with bullet points, such as: ●

How can I address this problem?

I attempted to switch to an alternative parser method, but it yielded unsatisfactory results, specifically causing text concatenation issues.

Comment: Which PDFminer exactly? There are several forks; the most popular and probably best maintained is `pdfminer.six` but it's a bit of a jungle. If you are using a different one, try switching?

Comment: Ultimately, if the PDF was composed in this order, that's probably what every PDF text extractor will extract. In the limit, try OCR:ing a rasterized version of the document instead.

Comment: (PDF lets you say things like "put the letter F here. Put the letter P over here. Then put the letter D over there" even if the visual rendering spells out "PDF". Mere text extraction will basically always produce "F", "P", "D" from this input.)

Comment: Things like this require you using a text extraction with subsequent sort by position of the text pieces on the page. Use an advanced package like PyMuPDF to do this.